# error when mysql db create in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

```
mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $MYSQL_DB; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  $MYSQL_DB.* TO $MYSQL_DB@localhost;"
```

Prints this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-simple' at line 1
```

db name is `losk_net-simple_ru`

Comment: You must backtick-quote the database name since it contains `-`.  You'll probably have to backslash escape the backticks in bash so they don't cause execution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "$MYSQL_DB"; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  "$MYSQL_DB".* TO "$MYSQL_DB"@localhost;"

same error

 mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$MYSQL_DB`; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  `$MYSQL_DB`.* TO `$MYSQL_DB`@localhost;"

error

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 1

Comment: See my full answer below. You need backslashes, and also to quote the value as a username in the `GRANT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your database name contains a hyphen `-`, you will need to backtick-quote it. In order to do that successfully inside a double-quoted Bash string, to surround a variable for expansion, you will need to backslash-escape the backticks.

Later, you reuse the variable `$MYSQL_DB` as a username. In that context, it must be single-quoted as a string like `'$MYSQL_DB'`.

```
mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`$MYSQL_DB\`; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`$MYSQL_DB\`.* TO '$MYSQL_DB'@localhost;"
#------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When testing this execution however, I receive:

> ERROR 1470 (HY000) at line 1: String 'losk_net-simple_ru' is too long for user name (should be no longer than 16)

You must therefore choose a different username than the database name if you encounter a similar error.

For reference on what types of quotes are used on MySQL strings and identifiers, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks). Although it is PHP-related, most of it is still relevant here.

In general, for this situation, *I would recommend against including a `-` in the database name*.  You will *always* have to backtick-quote it in every context, not just via Bash. Stick to the set of `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]` for identifiers, to save yourself future headaches.

Comment: I do this

 MYSQL_DB=`echo $USER | sed -e 's/\./\_/g;s/\-/\_/g' | cut -c1-15`

mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS" -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "$MYSQL_DB"; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  "$MYSQL_DB".* TO "$MYSQL_DB"@localhost;"

and all good now

thank you!